# Ubuntu Server 18.04 not detecting SAS drive

Tags: server, hard-drive, parted

I have two SAS drives 72GB. One is the system where Ubuntu server is installed on. The other is also connected but I can’t find it on the server. When I plug an HDD into the server, it outputs it as `/dev/sdb` but not the SAS?

I think my secondary SAS disk is inside `/dev/sda/`.

Because when I look at the following output, it shows two drive of 74GB.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 73.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  73.4GB  73.4GB  ext4

(parted)
```

Is this usually like this? And if not, could you guys explain to me how most companies do it? For Storage servers.

Comment: Is your server running on a standard consumer motherboard with a SATA controller? if so, are you using a SATA to SAS adapater for these hard drives? The SAS hard drives use a different protocol entirely than SATA, so if either of these cases are true, you won't be able to use SAS hard drives with your server unless you get a hardware controller (LSI MegaRAID is an inexpensive option)

Comment: I have an HPE ProLiant DL360 G6 - all SAS connectors

Comment: Use the [F8 key during boot](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/How-to-boot-to-RAID-setup-configuration-utility-on-DL380-G6-and/td-p/5658301) and see if the drives are configured in a RAID 1 or RAID 10, as those two settings would be why you only see 1 drive.  It has been a long time since I have worked on a HP DL360G6, but I believe that you can try configuring the drives to individual RAID 0 so that each can be seen separately.  You should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1109406/edit) your question and add more detail that could help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk` with the other drive plugged in?

Comment: Check into installing the hpssacli or just the ssacli which I believe that you can get from HPE themselves https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/sdr/repo/mcp/pool/non-free/.  When it is installed trying running `hpssacli ctrl all show config` or `ssacli ctrl all show config` and give the output.  It should show how many physical drives are detected.  You might need to also try `hpacucli` but the same rest of the commands.

Comment: I will let you guys know if I worked out, Im not at the server atm.

Comment: @Melebius But /dev/sda is 73.5 GB and 2 is 73.5GB ,,..

Comment: Right. According to your `parted` output, the disk `/dev/sda` contains two partitions: `/dev/sda1` with 1049kB (~ 1MB) and `/dev/sda2` with 73.4GB.